$L^p(\mathbb{T})$ is identified with tempered distibution (periodic)?
i know that, the space $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ canbe idenfitied with a tempered distributuion.
Can be the space $L^p(\mathbb{T})$ identified with a tempered distribution (periodic?)?

The torus can be defined as a quotient space of $\mathbb R^n.$ We can identify a function class $f\in L^p(\mathbb T)$ with a periodic function class $\hat f$ in $L^p_{loc}(\mathbb R^n)$ through
$$\hat f(x)=f(\overline x)$$
where ${\overline x}\in\mathbb T$ is the equivalence class of $x\in\mathbb R^n.$ Generally speaking locally $p$-integrable functions ($p\geq 1$) are distributions, but not necessarily tempered distributions. Periodicity comes to our aid and the integral of a fast decreasing function multiplied by a periodic locally integrable function is still finite, i.e., periodic locally integrable functions are tempered distributions.
It is more natural to define duality (between test functions and distributions) using the finite invariant measure on the compact group $\mathbb T,$ i.e., using periodic test functions and only integrating over one period in each dimension. Any infinitely differentiable function on $\mathbb T$ is a test function: no need for "fast decrease at infinity" because there is no infinity in a compact space, all functions have compact support. This also eliminates the distinction between distributions and tempered distributions. Any locally $p$-integrable periodic function is $p$-integrable with respect to that finite measure.

Thanks. But, is there an analogous with the fact: fourier transform is an isomorphism on tempered distribution? (changing $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $\mathbb{T}$)

Ah, Fourier analysis, that's a different question :-) Fourier analysis carries through to general unimodular Lie groups as long as the Fourier transform is considered on the dual group. The dual of a torus is a discrete lattice. The Fourier transform of a function on the torus (equivalently, a periodic function on $\mathbb R^n$) is a function on an $n$-dimensional lattice; these are the coefficients in (multivariate) Fourier series. The Plancherel isometry carries through: the quadratic integral of the original function (over one period) is the sum of the squared Fourier coefficients.

Or if you stick to the first, less natural definition, the Fourier transform as a tempered distribution would be an infinite sum of Dirac delta distributions on the points of the lattice, with the appropriate coefficient at every lattice point.
